# S3 restore fails The XML you provided was not well-formed

Tags: boto3

**Problem:**

I have written a sample code which will fetch object from a given S3 bucket , but the code is failing with an error :

**The error I am getting:**

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (MalformedXML)
>   when calling the RestoreObject operation: The XML you provided was not
>   well-formed or did not validate against our published schema.

**My Research effort:**

```
response = s3client.restore_object(Bucket='suddhasil-bucket-test-1', 
Key='20190101/US/temp.xls.xlsx',
                                   RestoreRequest={'Days':1, 
'GlacierJobParameters': {'Tier': 'Expedited'},
                                                   'Tier': 'Expedited',
                                                   'OutputLocation': {
                                                       'S3': 
{'BucketName': 'suddhasil-bucket-test-1',
                                                              'Prefix': 
'Backup_Restore'}}})
```

Any help would this would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the filter options that you missed. See [This](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.restore_object).

Answer (score 1):

if you are using output location if is not recommended to use 'Days':1, 
'GlacierJobParameters': {'Tier': 'Expedited'}